# Set hidden checkbox to true if other data condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I have a form that is divided up into a [Kendo UI Panel Bar](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/panelbar/index.html).  In the first panel I have a field that when populated with any text, checks a checkbox that is currently not visible and is located within the collapsed panel below it.

My issue is that the checkbox doesn't check.  I've read some posts on how a checkbox is disabled when it isn't visible.  Is there a workaround for this?

```
    function Validate(uid) {
    if ($("#SomeNumber_" + uid).val().length > 0) 
    {
        $("#MyCheckBox").attr('checked', true);  //This checkbox is display:none at the time this is set
        //Also tried these, but they didn't work:
        //$("#MyCheckBox").click();
        //var myCheckBox= document.getElementById("MyCheckBox");
        //myCheckBox.checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say invisible are you referring to CSS display: none;?

Comment: If the checkbox will always stay hidden, then why not use a hidden form field and store a boolean?

Comment: Yes.  Display:none is set on a parent element.  And no, the checkbox is not always hidden.  Some form fields are hidden until the user completes sections of the form to break up the form and make it not as overwhelming.  I did find the issue (comment on solution below).  I had an element with the same ID lurking around in the project somewhere and it was getting checked while the other wasn't.  Thanks so much for the help and quick responses, but I apologize for not having found that it wasn't something silly before I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested the display none on a checkbox by dynamically changing it through a button.  It works with display none set.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/hcWf8/1/

The following will set the attr of your checkbox to 'checked' -

this -

```
$('#MyCheckBox').attr('checked', true)
```

as well as

```
$('#MyCheckBox').attr('checked', 'checked')
```

as well as

```
document.getElementById('MyCheckBox').checked = true;
```

as well as

```
document.getElementById('MyCheckBox').checked = 'checked';
```

*edit - updated jsfiddle version to show these four methods

Comment: All answers do work.  I found that hiding somewhere else in the project there was an element with the same ID value.  It was checking that one while leave the other unchecked, making me believe that something was wrong.  Thanks for the help and sorry for the ultimately silly question.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$("#MyCheckBox").prop('checked', true);`

I have a similar usecase and can attest that it is possible to check a hidden checkbox.

I think the correct way to use attr is
`$("#MyCheckBox").attr('checked', 'checked');`